# Map table data to a ViewModel List in asp .Net MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a form that the user should enter the Owners details. The user is allowed to enter more than one owner and then submit the form. I created a jQuery array to push the values that the user entered and then I rendered these values in a table. Now I want to map the html tables values to a view model `List<OwnersViewModel>` when the user submits the form to send it to the server.

Any ideas please how can I do it?

My view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "WebsiteLicenseForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" })))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="main-form-group main-form-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.WebsiteLink, "الرابط الإلكتروني للمنصة ", new { @class = "control-label main-lable" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.WebsiteLink, new { @class = "form-control " })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.WebsiteLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="main-form-group main-form-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ApplicationLink, "الرابط الإلكتروني للتطبيق", new { @class = "control-label main-lable" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ApplicationLink, new { @class = "form-control " })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ApplicationLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />
    <h3>معلومات المالك</h3>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="main-form-group main-form-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.First_Name, "الاسم الأول", new { @class = "control-label main-lable" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.First_Name, new { @class = "form-control ", @required = "required", @id = "First_Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.First_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "First_NameError" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="main-form-group main-form-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Second_Name, "اسم الأب", new { @class = "control-label main-lable" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Second_Name, new { @class = "form-control ", @required = "required", @id = "Second_Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Second_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "Second_NameError" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="main-form-group main-form-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Third_Name, "اسم الجد", new { @class = "control-label main-lable" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Third_Name, new { @class = "form-control ", @required = "required", @id = "Third_Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Third_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "Third_NameError" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="main-form-group main-form-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Last_Name, "العائلة", new { @class = "control-label main-lable" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Last_Name, new { @class = "form-control ", @required = "required", @id = "Last_Name" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Last_Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "Last_NameError" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="main-form-group main-form-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OwnerNid, "الهوية الوطنية", new { @class = "control-label main-lable", })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OwnerNid, new { @class = "form-control ", @required = "required", @id = "OwnerNid", @type = "number" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OwnerNid, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "OwnerNidError" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="main-form-group main-form-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OwnerMobile, "رقم الهاتف", new { @class = "control-label main-lable" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OwnerMobile, new { @class = "form-control ", @required = "required", @id = "OwnerMobile" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OwnerMobile, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "OwnerMobileError" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="main-form-group main-form-input">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OwneEmail, "البريد الإلكتروني", new { @class = "control-label main-lable" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.OwneEmail, new { @class = "form-control ", @required = "required", @id = "OwneEmail" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OwneEmail, "", new { @class = "text-danger", @id = "OwneEmailError" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <br /><br />
            <input type="button" value="add another owner " class="main-submit" id="addOWner" name="AddOwner" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <br />

    <table class="table main-table" id="OwnersTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>الاسم الأول</th>
                <th>اسم الأب</th>
                <th>اسم الجد</th>
                <th>العائلة</th>
                <th>رقم الهوية</th>
                <th>الهاتف</th>
                <th>البريد الإلكتروني</th>
                <th>حذف</th>
            </tr>
           
        </thead>
    </table>

    <div class="main-form-submit">
        <input type="submit" value="حفظ" class="main-submit" id="submit" name="submit" />
    </div>
}
```

My jQuery function :

```
$("#addOWner").click(function () {
    
    var Owners = [];

    Owners.push({
        'First_Name': $("#First_Name").val(),
        'Second_Name': $("#Second_Name").val(),
        'Third_Name': $("#Third_Name").val(),
        'Last_Name': $("#Last_Name").val(),
        'OwnerNid': $("#OwnerNid").val(),
        'OwnerMobile': $("#OwnerMobile").val(),
        'OwneEmail': $("#OwneEmail").val(),
    });

    for (i = 0; i < Owners.length; i++) {
        var content = "<tr>"
        for (i = 0; i < Owners.length; i++) {
            content += '<td>' + Owners[i].First_Name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + Owners[i].Second_Name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + Owners[i].Third_Name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + Owners[i].Last_Name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + Owners[i].OwnerNid + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + Owners[i].OwnerMobile + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + Owners[i].OwneEmail + '</td>';
            content += "<td><div><button id='" + Owners[i].OwnerNid + "' class='delete' name='delete' type='button'>DELETE</button></div></td>";
        }
        content += "</tr>"

        $('#OwnersTable').append(content);
    };
});
```

Submit form function:

```
$('#WebsiteLicenseForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).ajaxSubmit({
        type: "Post",
        url: '/Licenses/SubminWebSiteLicense', // the file to call
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

My main model class:

```
public class WebsiteLicenseViewModel
{
    public string WebsiteName { get; set; }
    public string WebsiteLink { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationLink { get; set; }

    public string CrNumber { get; set; }
    public string OwnerNid { get; set; }
    public string OwnerMobile { get; set; }
    public string OwnerEmail { get; set; }

    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Second_Name { get; set; }
    public string Third_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }

    public string AttachmentUrl { get; set; }

    public List<OwnersViewModel> OwnersList { get; set; }
}
```

My OwnersViewModel:

```
public class OwnersViewModel
{
    public string OwnerNid { get; set; }
    public string OwnerMobile { get; set; }
    public string OwnerEmail { get; set; }

    public string First_Name { get; set; }
    public string Second_Name { get; set; }
    public string Third_Name { get; set; }
    public string Last_Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can push table values to array and pass it to controller as additional data where you can convert it to list. For example:

```
$('#WebsiteLicenseForm').on('submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    //get array from table
    var owners = [];
    $('#OwnersTable').eq(0).find('tr').each((r, row) => owners.push($(row).find('td,th').map((c, cell) => $(cell).text()).toArray()))

    //define form
     var form = $('#WebsiteLicenseForm');
   
    $.ajax({
        type: "Post",
        url: '/Licenses/SubminWebSiteLicense', // the file to call
        data: form.serialize() + '&owners=' + JSON.stringify(owners),
        dataType : 'json'
        success: function (response) {
            alert("Success");
        }
    });

    return false;
})
```

Or you can add owners array to model and then append additional data to form before passing it to controller.